# Flutter : 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The actual problem is that I cant run this command : `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`
as you can see from this link : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/friendlyeats-flutter/#12
im trying to learn firebase with my flutter project ..in general I dont understand the index thing here and i would really appreciate  your effort if you do ... I have added a new terminal but still getting this error ...please help me solve this problem .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install Firebase tools first, run in your terminal

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

Comment: I get this error while running this command : 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
the terminal of android studio or CMD of my windows ?

Comment: Then install npm first.

Comment: could you please give a link or something about how to install it ?

Comment: Google how to install npm on windows.

Comment: Hi developers out there ...first install npm then from your terminal run npm install -g firebase-tools then open android srudio and run firebase init then run this command :  firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes     Now everything works as intended.